# How to convert _ to - in urls for codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

Been trying to learn codeigniter, 1 problem I had though is that if I had a function say

top_10()

It would mean that my urls will be something like

..../top_10/

Which is fine but I prefer - more than _ for urls. I tried changing my function names to top-10(), but it results in a syntax error it seems (even if it doesn't it results in a ugly function name), Is there a way to let codeigniter auto converts all the _ in my controller functions to - when it comes to the urls?

.../top_10/ -> .../top-10/ for all other similar controller functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URI routing rule
something like :
`$route['controller/top-10'] = "controller/top_10";`

Add this line in the routes.php file inside `application/config/routes.php`

Here `controller/top-10` will be the part of your url which will be routed to the desired function provided by on the right hand side.
also if you aren't using mod_rewrite to rewrite your url then your URL will appear some thing like
http://localhost/index.php/controller/top-10

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `application/config/routes.php` folder if there isn't a line for translating uri dashes then add this line: `$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;`

If `$route['translate_uri_dashes']` already exists, simply set it's value to true.